# SQL command denied to user selector

Tags: sql, sintaxe

Estou tentando dar update no meu banco de dados, e setar o visible de todos esses vouchers para 0, estou utilizando ide para o comando e ele acusa um erro e acredito que seja na syntax, alguem pode me ajudar?

> UPDATE command denied to user 'selector'@'135.127.72.253' for table 'voucher'

```
UPDATE voucher
SET visible = 0
WHERE (city_name = 'Manaus' AND campus_name = 'Nucleo');
```

Comment: No erro fica bem explícito o que está acontecendo: O usuario 'selector' não tem permissão para executar um `update`. Você teria acesso ao usuário `root` do banco?

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português, eu editei sua pergunta para ficar mais fácil para nós compreendermos. Recomendo visitar o [tour] para conhecer um pouco mais como o Stack Overflow funciona. Seja bem vindo :)

Comment: como o @JorgeMatheus comentou, o usuário que está usando para executar o update não tem permissão, converse com o DBA para que ele resolva isso